# What's a good way to use variables in SQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
  A.ID,
  CASE
    WHEN A.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR'
    ELSE 'ADULT'
  END as CATEGORY

FROM PEOPLE as A

INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE as B on B.STUFF = A.CATEGORY
```

The above code won't work, because A.CATEGORY is not a valid column in the PEOPLE table, but I would like to somehow reuse CATEGORY in a join, without doing the CASE statement again.

That should be possible, right?

Thanks!

LE: I should mention that I'm looking for a solution that performs well with a lot of data. The code I gave here is just a basic mock-up.

Comment: Might be worth reading the Logical Processing Order of [SELECT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx): " because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses" `JOIN` is step 3.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to a subquery is a [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server. It is effectively the same as a subquery but you can lay it out in a nicer format so it may be easier to read.

Your example would then be something like this:

```
;WITH PeopleExtended AS
(
    SELECT
        A.ID,
        CASE
            WHEN A.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR'
            ELSE 'ADULT'
        END as CATEGORY
    FROM
        PEOPLE AS A
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    PeopleExtended AS A
    INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE AS B ON B.STUFF = A.CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. It is very clean.
Also, the link you provided shows that a CTE can be used to:
"Reference the resulting table multiple times in the same statement." which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You should try a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      A.ID,
      CASE WHEN A.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR' ELSE 'ADULT' END as CATEGORY
    FROM PEOPLE as A
) SUBQUERY,
INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE as B on B.STUFF = SUBQUERY.CATEGORY
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to SQL, but do subqueries perform well, given a lot of data and more complex queries?

Comment: It's ok and commonly used in *not-so*-user-friendly DB engines. i.e. in Oracle you don't have a LIMIT keyword, so you are using a double subquery with rownumber between 0 and 50 to get 50 first rows. You should just keep in mind, that all rows from subquery are selected, and then passed to upper-level query.

Comment: @Xardas: the query optimization process in a database may choose not to execute the entire subquery first, but may execute it together with the main query, and may even optimize them together.

Comment: Yeah, true, but it's good to _keep in mind the possibility_ of full subquery selection execution, to prevent resource leakage.

Answer (score 1):

I would add this: If you get the performance you need with the CTE approach use it. The modularity and in memory aspects of CTEs are very appealing. If not:

1. Create a local temporary table using a [minimally logged](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) SELECT…INTO
2. Add an index
3. Use the local temporary table in your outer query

```sql
SELECT
  A.ID,
  CASE
    WHEN A.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR'
    ELSE 'ADULT'
  END as CATEGORY
INTO #MyCategory
FROM PEOPLE as A;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_MyCategory ON #MyCategory(ID, CATEGORY); 
GO

SELECT A.ID, A.CATEGORY
FROM #MyCategory as A
INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE as B on B.STUFF = A.CATEGORY;
GO
```

Depending on the actual complexity of your "real" query, the scale of your data, and the hardware resources available to you, one approach will perform better than another.

If you can afford to take the time, its always a good idea to try more than one approach and compare the execution plans.

For more details and insight I highly recommend chapter 7 of this book:

[Inside Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008: T-SQL Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626022)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sub query to use it like below

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT  A.ID, CASE WHEN A.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR' ELSE 'ADULT' END as CATEGORY
   FROM PEOPLE as A
) t1
INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE as B on B.STUFF = t1.CATEGORY
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    CAT.CATEGORY

FROM PEOPLE as A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
             CASE WHEN AT.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR' ELSE 'ADULT' END as CATEGORY) CAT
INNER JOIN OTHERPEOPLE as B on B.STUFF = CAT.CATEGORY
```

Comment: Yes, CROSS APPLY would work nicely (provided it's SQL Server 2005+), but you are overcomplicating it. `CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN AT.AGE < 21 THEN 'MINOR' ELSE 'ADULT' END as CATEGORY) CAT` would be just enough.

Comment: @AndriyM you're right. `CROSS APPLY` can use references of another table...(updated answer)